# Finding Events During a Timeframe

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to figure out a query that could work for multiple situations. In a nutshell the data can be in one of twosituations. Lets say I'm looking for the record_id for events happened during a given time frame: 6/26/2012 10:00AM and 6/27/2012 11:00AM The records can look like this in the database:

```
Record    Event     Time
1         Start     6/26/2012 10:05AM
1         End       6/26/2012 10:45AM
2         Start     6/26/2012 09:55AM
2         End       6/26/2012 11:05AM
```

Getting record 1 is easy, just using the between function, but I'm stumbling trying to figure out a query to return both records 1 and 2.

Suggestions?

Comment: Um, widen your `between` criteria so that it includes record 2?

Comment: How far should I widen it? What if in my example I had an event that started on 6/26/2012 9:45AM and ended on 6/26/2012 9:59AM. This event was not taking place during the time frame I'm looking for but if I widen the time frame I could pick this record up which I do not want to do.

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is that, if either the Start or End records are within my time frame, then I want both Start and End records for the event?

Comment: Kind of, think of it as looking at a pump running. During any given time frame I want to see if the pump ran or was running and return that record for its start and stop time. really isn't a pump but that is the best analogy I can think of right now.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply widen the range, but this may bring back different records than you intend.

```
SELECT  RECORD, EVENT, TIME 
FROM SO_RecordEvent AS R
WHERE TIme BETWEEN  '6/26/2012 9:55AM'  AND '6/26/2012 11:06AM'
```

This will return all records for anything that has either a start or end time within the range, including the associated records falling outside of the range (In other words records that only have one time in the range - but began before or ended after - it will still show the start or end time outside of it) and allow you you shorten your range.

```
 ;WITH X AS 
 (
    SELECT RECORD,EVENT,TIME FROM SO_RecordEvent 
 )
 SELECT R.RECORD,R.EVENT,R.TIME 
 FROM SO_RecordEvent AS R
 INNER JOIN X ON R.Record = X.Record
 WHERE X.TIme BETWEEN  '6/26/2012 10:05AM'  AND '6/26/2012 11:05AM'
 GROUP BY R.RECORD,R.EVENT,R.TIME
```

**But I think you may really want something like this**, which truly gives you everything that was started during that time, even if it started AND ended outside of the range, as is your record 2 example.

### **EDIT**

Changed logic - instead of addressing situations decided to think about it this way - anything that started within start and end, anything that ended within start and end, and anything that started before and ended after. I think this covers anything that runs during this time (starts before ends within, starts and ends within, starts within and ends after, and starts before and ends after)

```
  SELECT X.RECORD,X.TIME AS STARTTIME,Y.TIME AS ENDTIME 
  FROM SO_RecordEvent AS X
  INNER JOIN SO_RecordEvent Y ON Y.Record = X.Record AND Y.EVENT = 'END'
  WHERE  X.EVENT = 'START'
  AND 
  ((X.TIME >= '6/26/2012 10:00AM' AND X.TIME <= '6/26/2012 11:00AM')
  OR (Y.TIME >= '6/26/2012 10:00AM' AND Y.TIME <= '6/26/2012 11:00AM')
  OR (X.TIME <= '6/26/2012 10:00AM' AND Y.TIME >= '6/26/2012 11:00AM'))
```

Variables to play with:

```
 DECLARE @START datetime, @END datetime
 SET @START = '6/26/2012 10:00AM'
 SET @END = '6/26/2012 11:00AM'

   SELECT X.RECORD,X.TIME AS STARTTIME,Y.TIME AS ENDTIME 
   FROM SO_RecordEvent AS X
   INNER JOIN SO_RecordEvent Y ON Y.Record = X.Record AND Y.EVENT = 'END'
   WHERE  X.EVENT = 'START'
   AND 
  ((X.TIME >= @START AND X.TIME <= @END)
  OR (Y.TIME >= @START AND Y.TIME <= @END)
  OR (X.TIME <= @START AND Y.TIME >= @END))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does appear to be what I'm looking for, will do some more testing to verify the results. Marking it as an answer.

Comment: Just ran into one record issue, it had a start time within the time frame specified but an end time outside of this range, the query didn't return this result. Going to take a look to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: What if the event starts and finishes multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably join the table to itself - something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Table leftside
    JOIN Table rightside
        ON leftside.Record = rightside.Record
WHERE
    leftside.Event = 'Start'
    and rightside.Event = 'End'
    and [whatever time you want] >= leftside.Time
    and [whatever time you want] <= rightside.Time
```

EDIT: Example to demonstrate

```
create table thingy (
    record int,
    event varchar(10),
    time datetime )

insert thingy (record,event,time) values (1,'Start','6/26/2012 10:05AM')
insert thingy (record,event,time) values (1,'End','6/26/2012 10:45AM ')
insert thingy (record,event,time) values (2,'Start','6/26/2012 09:55AM')
insert thingy (record,event,time) values (2,'End','6/26/2012 11:05AM')

DECLARE @mytime datetime
SET @mytime = '6/26/2012 9:58AM'

SELECT * 
FROM 
        thingy leftside 
    JOIN thingy rightside 
        ON leftside.Record = rightside.Record 
WHERE 
    leftside.Event = 'Start' 
    and rightside.Event = 'End' 
    and @mytime >= leftside.Time 
    and @mytime <= rightside.Time 

SET @mytime = '6/26/2012 10:10AM'
SELECT * 
FROM 
    thingy leftside 
    JOIN thingy rightside 
        ON leftside.Record = rightside.Record 
WHERE 
    leftside.Event = 'Start' 
    and rightside.Event = 'End' 
    and @mytime >= leftside.Time 
    and @mytime <= rightside.Time
```

Seems to give what I would expect - 1 row for the first query, 2 for the second.

Comment: I gave it a try and I didn't get what i was expecting, actually got nothing, but I'll play with it and see if I can get something to work

Answer (score 0):

Get record #s of all events that fall within the given range:

```
SELECT Record
FROM atable
WHERE Time BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

Now just get all rows whose record #s match those in the above query's result set, i.e. like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE Record IN (
  SELECT Record
  FROM atable
  WHERE Time BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be using the following:

```
WITH recs AS (
SELECT Record, MIN(tme) AS startTime, MAX(tme) AS endTime
FROM records
GROUP BY Record
)
SELECT * FROM
records
WHERE startTime >= @eventsAfter
AND endTime <= @eventsBefore
```

(this is how I interpreted your question, at least)