# How to write SQL query for the following case.?

Tags: sql

I have one Change Report Table which has two columns ChangedTime,FileName [image]

Please consider this table has over 1000 records

Here I need to query all the changes based on following factors

```
i) Interval (i.e-1mins )
ii) No of files
```

It means when we have given Interval 1 min and No Of files 10. 
    If the the no of changed files more than 10 in any of the 1 minute interval, we need to get all the changed files exists in that 1 minute interval

Example:

```
  i) Consider we have 15 changes in the interval 11:52 to 11:53
  ii)And consider we have 20 changes in the interval 12:58 to 12:59
```

Now my expected results would be 35 records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say, "over 1000 records" I hear "not very many"

Comment: So pls consider over 1000 million records

Comment: How accurate is your "changedTime"? Is it down to the second or is it just the minute? Does it include the day?

Comment: which DBMS are you using??

Comment: It is down up to second. you can see the clear picture from the above image

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the image, imgur is blocked here at work ...

Comment: were you think to make this a stored proc and dynamicly pass in the Interval? or did you just want to run the query and manually enter the time frame?

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231264/finding-events-during-a-timeframe seems to do what your looking for

Comment: Oh.. Changed time is a normal DateTime which contains Year:Day:Hour:Minute:second

Comment: Hi Dev N00B, I just want to run the query manually

Comment: is the 1 min interval always start with 0 sec and end  with 59 sec? consider the scenario i do not have any changes from 33 min 0 sec to 30 min 29 sec. then from 30 min 30 sec to 31 min 0 sec i have 9 changes and from 31 min 1 sec to 31 min 29 sec we have another 9 edits. Does that mean in interval of 1 min we have 18 changes?

Comment: YOu need an alias on your table not repeating the tablename twice. Chenge teh second instance of [MyDB].[dbo].[Log_Table.in_PC]
 to  Logtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the interval and then do the count.  Assuming that an interval starting at time 0 is ok, the following should work:

```
declare @interval int = 1;
declare @limit int = 10;

select sum(cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by DATEDIFF(minute, 0, ChangedTime)/@interval
     ) t
where cnt >= @limit;
```

If you have another time in mind for when intervals should start, then substitute that for `0`.

EDIT:

For your particular query:

```
select sum(ChangedTime)
from (select count(*) as ChangedTime
  from [MyDB].[dbo].[Log_Table.in_PC] 
  group by DATEDIFF(minute, 0, ChangedTime)/@interval
 ) t
where ChangedTime >= @limit;
```

You can't have a three part alias name on a subquery.  `t` will do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. i am getting an error Incorrect syntax near '.' ...My table name has the char '.' but i have enclosed the name with []

Comment: @kombsh . . . Although SQL is quite clever with errors, it doesn't generate errors against non-existent characters.  The code in the answer has no `'.'` character, so it is somethingin the translation.  Can you edit your question and add the code that is generating the error.

Comment: Sorry now I am getting an error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: @kombsh . . . That is a really arcane error when the `group by` is a constant.  I was using `getdate()` to test the syntax and left it in instead of your column name.  Fixed.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Thanks for your help .. it's working now..and one more help ..my expected result would be 25 rows not the count 25... can you help me once again

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:
You count the number of records using the [`COUNT()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) function.
Then you limit the selection with the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(FileName) 
FROM "YourTable" 
WHERE ChangedTime >= "StartInteval" 
  AND ChangedTime <= "EndInterval";
```

Another method that is useful in a where clause is `BETWEEN` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx.

You didn't state which SQL DB you are using so I assume its MSSQL.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. But here i don't know the STAR and END interval..I just know 1 minute interval that exits in any of the time in the table

Comment: ah i didnt see that one :)
then the answer stated by @gordon-linoff is what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (select a.FileName, 
b.ChangedTime startTime, 
a.ChangedTime endTime, 
DATEDIFF ( minute , a.ChangedTime , b.ChangedTime ) timeInterval
from yourtable a, yourtable b
where a.FileName = b.FileName
and a.ChangedTime > b.ChangedTime
and DATEDIFF ( minute , a.ChangedTime , b.ChangedTime ) = 1) temp
group by temp.FileName
```